# string stream vs direct string

Tags: c++, stomp

I'm attempting to send a STOMP frame to a server. I first tried to create the message directly using std::string, but the server kept complaining I am doing it wrong. But, when I created the message using stringstream, it works. Anyone can spot my mistake? The code is as shown. It complains it can't find the terminating \0 at the end of the message (parsingmissingnullinbody).

```
bool CheckResponse(const std::string& response)
{
// We do not parse the whole message. We only check that it contains some
// expected items.
bool ok {true};
ok &= response.find("ERROR") != std::string::npos;
ok &= response.find("ValidationInvalidAuth") != std::string::npos;
std::cout << response << "\n";
return ok;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(connect_to_network_events){
    // Always start with an I/O context object.
    boost::asio::io_context ioc {};

    // Create also a tls context
    boost::asio::ssl::context ctx{boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12_client};
    // Connection targets
    const std::string url {"ltnm.learncppthroughprojects.com"};
    const std::string port {"443"};
    const std::string endpoint {"/network-events"};

    // The class under test
    WebSocketClient client {url, endpoint, port, ioc, ctx};

    // MY ATTEMPT AT CREATING MESSAGE DIRECTLY, THIS FAILED
    // const std::string message {"STOMP\naccept-version:1.2\nhost:transportforlondon.com\nlogin:fake_username\npasscode:fake_password\n\n\0"};

    // THE FOLLOWING SUCCEEDED INSTEAD
    const std::string username {"fake_username"};
    const std::string password {"fake_password"};
    std::stringstream ss {};
    ss << "STOMP" << std::endl
       << "accept-version:1.2" << std::endl
       << "host:transportforlondon.com" << std::endl
       << "login:" << username << std::endl
       << "passcode:" << password << std::endl
       << std::endl // Headers need to be followed by a blank line.
       << '\0'; // The body (even if absent) must be followed by a NULL octet.
    const std::string message {ss.str()};

    std::string response;
    // We use these flags to check that the connection, send, receive functions
    // work as expected.
    bool connected {false};
    bool messageSent {false};
    bool messageReceived {false};
    bool messageMatches {false};
    bool disconnected {false};

    // Our own callbacks
    auto onSend {[&messageSent](auto ec) {
        messageSent = !ec;
    }};
    auto onConnect {[&client, &connected, &onSend, &message](auto ec) {
        connected = !ec;
        if (!ec) {
            client.Send(message, onSend);
        }
    }};
    auto onClose {[&disconnected](auto ec) {
        disconnected = !ec;
    }};
    auto onReceive {[&client,
                      &onClose,
                      &messageReceived,
                      &messageMatches,
                      &message,
                      &response](auto ec, auto received) {
        messageReceived = !ec;
        response = received;
        client.Close(onClose);
    }};

    // We must call io_context::run for asynchronous callbacks to run.
    client.Connect(onConnect, onReceive);
    ioc.run();

    BOOST_CHECK(CheckResponse(response));
}
```

Comment: Send the actual binary terminator that the message processor is looking for, not `std::endl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an `std::string` from `const char *` will ignore the terminating NULL character. You could use the `char[]` constructor but I think it won't fit your use case.

Example:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string message1 {"STOMP\naccept-version:1.2\nhost:transportforlondon.com\nlogin:fake_username\npasscode:fake_password\n\n\0"};
    std::cout << message1.length() << std::endl;
    
    std::string message2 {"STOMP\naccept-version:1.2\nhost:transportforlondon.com\nlogin:fake_username\npasscode:fake_password\n\n"};
    std::cout << message2.length() << std::endl;
    
    message2.push_back('\0');
    std::cout << message2.length() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
97
97
98
```

So you just need to create the message without the terminating NULL character and then append `\0`.

**Update:** If you are in `C++14` you may want to use string literals:

```
using namespace std::string_literals;

// ... 

std::string message = "STOMP\naccept-version:1.2\nhost:transportforlondon.com\nlogin:fake_username\npasscode:fake_password\n\n\0"s;
```

Note the `s` at the end of the string.

Comment: It works! So when creating strings from std::string, the \0 is not regarded as literal, thus we need to append it manually?

Comment: One of `std::string`'s constructors takes a `const char *`, aka a C-string. C-strings are NULL terminated. i.e.: NULL marks the end of the string but it is not part of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use string constructor with iterators to copy all the characters including trailing \0

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

// helper function to copy ALL the chars including terminating 0 into a string
template<std::size_t N>
auto create_message(const char(&chars)[N])
{
    std::string message(std::begin(chars), std::end(chars));
    return message;
}

int main()
{
    auto message = create_message("STOMP\naccept-version:1.2\nhost:transportforlondon.com\nlogin:fake_username\npasscode:fake_password\n\n");

    // check last character in string is actually 0
    assert(message[message.length() - 1] == 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```cpp
> const std::string message {"STOMP\naccept-version:1.2\nhost:transportforlondon.com\nlogin:fake_username\npasscode:fake_password\n\n\0"};
> ```

This fails because you are constructing `message` using the `std::string` constructor that takes in only a **null-terminated** `const char*` pointer and it will calculate the string length by looking for a terminating `'\0'`.  Since your string literal contains an explicit `'\0'` in it, that is where the constructor stops reading in characters.  The `'\0'` itself is not copied.

To fix this, you need to specify the string literal's length *including* the explicit `'\0'`, eg:

```cpp
const std::string message ("STOMP\naccept-version:1.2\nhost:transportforlondon.com\nlogin:fake_username\npasscode:fake_password\n\n\0", 98);
```

Alternatively, let the compiler figure out the length for you:

```cpp
const char msg[] = "STOMP\naccept-version:1.2\nhost:transportforlondon.com\nlogin:fake_username\npasscode:fake_password\n\n\0"; // will include an implicit '\0' after the explicit '\0'...
const std::string message (msg, std::size(msg)-1); // -1 to ignore the implicit '\0'...
```

The reason the `std::stringstream` approach works is because `<< '\0'` is inserting an actual `'\0'` character into the stream, which is then included in the `std::string` returned by `str()`.